# Configure 2 sshd services

Tags: linux, services, sshd

I have the following task:

1. Configure a ssh service so that user *special* cannot connect through it.
2. Open a ssh server on port 2222 listening to 127.0.0.1. Limit this service so that just user *special* can connect. It is desirable to create a service for that.

My approach is based on https://askubuntu.com/questions/324503/2-sshd-configurations-1-for-internal-and-1-external

1. Modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` adding `DenyUsers special`
2. Modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config_external` setting `Port 2222` and `ListenAddress 127.0.0.1`
3. Create `/lib/systemd/system/sshd-external.service` and modify it to include the new configuration as `ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config_external`

The `sshd.service` launches:

```
[root@bastion 0 ~]# systemctl status sshd
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-09-19 12:54:16 UTC; 19min ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
 Main PID: 1418 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─1418 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Sep 19 12:54:16 bastion.7eca.example.opentlc.com systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Sep 19 12:54:16 bastion.7eca.example.opentlc.com sshd[1418]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Sep 19 12:54:16 bastion.7eca.example.opentlc.com sshd[1418]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Sep 19 12:54:16 bastion.7eca.example.opentlc.com systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
Sep 19 12:54:30 bastion.7eca.example.opentlc.com sshd[1884]: Accepted publickey for hesteban-redhat.com from 88.128.92.150 port 40092 ssh2: RSA SHA256:sWujd4yvXg62et5LzOAR7BhMGvQ5+vBNSUrgrVdUdEs
Sep 19 12:55:48 bastion.7eca.example.opentlc.com sshd[1929]: Received disconnect from 222.186.30.35 port 58344:11:  [preauth]
Sep 19 12:55:48 bastion.7eca.example.opentlc.com sshd[1929]: Disconnected from 222.186.30.35 port 58344 [preauth]
Sep 19 13:13:52 bastion.7eca.example.opentlc.com sshd[2219]: Received disconnect from 222.186.42.155 port 10630:11:  [preauth]
Sep 19 13:13:52 bastion.7eca.example.opentlc.com sshd[2219]: Disconnected from 222.186.42.155 port 10630 [preauth]
```

But the issue comes when I launch the `sshd-extended.service`

```
[root@bastion 0 ~]# systemctl start sshd-external
Job for sshd-external.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status sshd-external.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@bastion 0 ~]# journalctl -xe
        -- Unit sshd-external.service has begun starting up.
Sep 21 07:16:41 bastion.7eca.example.opentlc.com sshd[2228]: error: Bind to port 2222 on 127.0.0.1 failed: Permission denied.
Sep 21 07:16:41 bastion.7eca.example.opentlc.com sshd[2228]: fatal: Cannot bind any address.
Sep 21 07:16:41 bastion.7eca.example.opentlc.com systemd[1]: sshd-external.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=255/n/a
Sep 21 07:16:41 bastion.7eca.example.opentlc.com systemd[1]: Failed to start OpenSSH server daemon.
-- Subject: Unit sshd-external.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit sshd-external.service has failed.
```

Then if I try again the problem it says is that 127.0.0.1 port 2222 is already in use

---

### EDIT

The `sshd-extended.service` is:

```
[root@bastion 0 ~]# cat /lib/systemd/system/sshd-external.service 
[Unit]
Description=OpenSSH server daemon
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=network.target sshd-keygen.service
Wants=sshd-keygen.service

[Service]
Type=notify
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/sshd
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/sshd -D $OPTIONS -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config_external
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Could you show the actual .service file that you are using? It looks like you might have added parameters that sshd doesn't support. (Also, don't put local customizations in /lib.)

Comment: I have edited thepost